# Varchar2 to Date for sysdate comparison

Tags: sql, oracle, varchar, to-date, sysdate

A table I am querying has dates stored as varchar2. I need to compare the dates stored as varchar2 with sysdate using `BETWEEN sysdate-1 AND sysdate-30` (to return varchar2 dates from the last month).

When specifying `TO_DATE(varchar2, 'DD-MON-YYYY')` I get error "literal does not match format string".

I am stuck as Oracle documentation says this is an acceptable format for `TO_DATE()` when converting from varchar2.

**UPDATE**: This is a corporate database, I did not design the DB and can only work with what I have available. The data set is enormous and is automatically updated by SCADA devices, over 10,000 devices daily.

```
SELECT device_name, read_date, sysdate

FROM oracle_database

------- Data Returned by query --------

device_name read_date   sysdate
Device 1    5/14/2013   22-Sep-14
Device 2    5/14/2013   22-Sep-14
Device 3    5/14/2013   22-Sep-14
Device 4    5/14/2013   22-Sep-14
Device 5    5/14/2013   22-Sep-14
Device 6    5/14/2013   22-Sep-14
Device 7    5/14/2013   22-Sep-14
```

Results from using TO_DATE

> SELECT device_name, TO_DATE(read_date, 'DD-MON-YY'), sysdate
>
> ------- Data Returned by query ----------
>
> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: Can you give an example of your input?

Comment: You have to use a format that matches the strings you actually have stored. You have to hope they are all in the same format and are valid... It's possibly to have a function that tries several formats but that's messay, esp. if you have a mix of DD/MM and MM/DD dates. This is why dates shouldn't be stored as strings... Anyway, if you show some sample data and the dates they represent (if it isn't obvious) then a suitable model can be suggested.

Comment: @Alex, I hope you won't mind if I give a try to answer based on "Why to not store date as string". I have included the link to Ed Stevens' article about it, which is quite awesome. And I use the same link everywhere to answer similar questions.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - while it's valid, I don't think it explains the error the OP is seeing, or what to do about it. (Other than storing as a date; but then the model problem moves to the insert, maybe). But then until the format the strings are in is known, not much else to say...

Comment: @Alex, I thought of telling OP to alter his session with `nls_date_format` if he is unsure about the nls settings, but I refrained since I amateurs playing more at query level format than session level, and it will override the session level settings. Let's see what OP tells us regarding further details. I will try to improvise my answer based on new inputs by OP.

Comment: You definitively should show us a small but significant sample of your "date" column. Clearly there should be some discrepancies between the mask you try to use and the actual date format.

Comment: I have updated the comment with additional feedback, thank you @AlexPoole

Answer (score 1):

Given your data, the proper format is very probably `MM/DD/YYYY`. It will match both single and double digits months or days.

- `MM` : month from 01 to 12 (leading `0` not mandatory by default)
- `\` : *any* punctuation sign
- `DD` : day from 01 to 31 (leading `0` not mandatory by default)
- `\` : *any* punctuation sign
- `YYYY` : year

See Oracle's [documentation about datetime Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212)  for the details.

Here is example:

```
-- Some test data
WITH testdata AS (
  SELECT '5/14/2013' as d FROM DUAL
  UNION SELECT '05/14/2013' FROM DUAL
  UNION SELECT '5/1/2013' FROM DUAL
  UNION SELECT '5/01/2013' FROM DUAL
  UNION SELECT '6-6-2013' FROM DUAL)

-- Actual query demonstrating the use of the MM/DD/YYYY format
select d, TO_DATE(d,'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM testdata
```

Producing:

```
D           TO_DATE(D,'MM/DD/YYYY')
05/14/2013  05/14/2013
5/01/2013   05/01/2013
5/1/2013    05/01/2013
5/14/2013   05/14/2013
6-6-2013    06/06/2013
```

---

If you really need to enforce the fact that your date components are separated by `/` (and not by any other *punctuation sign*), you should use `fxfmMM/DD/YYYY` instead:

- the `fx`  flag force *strict* comparison, both for punctuation and number of digits in the format
- the `fm`  flag relax that comparison to allow *up* to the number of specified digits

Comment: How do I join the testdata subquery with my devices table? I cannot use date as it is not unique. I read the Oracle documentation pertaining to WITH and still drawing a blank.

Also, given the above, it doesn't seem possible to return any data outside of the date range in the subquery. 

For instance:

WHERE sysdate BETWEEN (sysdate-1) AND (sysdate-30)

Comment: @tx_query - `testdata` is just to provide some example data like yours, and show how it's converted successfully to a date with this format model. You don't need `testdata` or a join. Just use `TO_DATE(read_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')` in your original query.

Comment: @AlexPoole For what it's worth, I found out that the format was yyyy-mm-dd and went with

ROUND(avg(valve_pressure) over (PARTITION BY unique_id order by to_date(read_date,'yyyy-mm-dd') range between 30 preceding and current row)) MA_30

Big thanks to the two of you for your prompt and courteous replies.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT device_name, TO_DATE(read_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), sysdate
```

Comment: The answer can become more valuable if you are adding some explanation and links to documentation, so the original poster and other users can actually learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your design is flawed. You should never have `DATE` as `VARCHAR2` data type.

Secondly, while comparing the dates, and converting a `date literal` to a `DATE`, always specify the same format mask on both sides.

To convert a string to date, use `TO_DATE` with proper format mask.

To convert a date to string, use `TO_CHAR` with same format mask.

Make sure, while comparing the values in an expression, you `explicitly` convert the data type on either sides of the `comparison operator` to avoid `implicit data type conversion`.

And you must read this excellent article bybEd Stevens, http://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/